# Cómo desactivar el Project build Sync al abrir Android Studio 3.3?

Tags: android-studio

El problema es que se tarda tantos minutos el `Android Studio` en estar listo, debido a que automáticamente (no sé como) se inicia el proceso de construcción (build) del proyecto a la par que comienza a ejecutarse también `Android Studio`.

¿Debería configurar parámetros de un archivo de .gradle, para evitar toda esta larga espera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este caso me parece que deberías de [**Activar el modo sin conexión para Gradle**](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config).

> [**Activar el modo sin conexión para Gradle**](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config): si tu ancho de banda es limitado, activa el modo sin conexión para evitar que Gradle intente
>   descargar dependencias faltantes durante tu compilación. Si faltan
>   dependencias, Gradle mostrará una falla en lugar de intentar
>   descargarlas cuando esté activado el modo sin conexión.

Ve a `File` > `Settings` > `Build, Execution, Deployment, Gradle` y activa la opción :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De otra forma siempre se estarán descargando las dependencias y provocará que tu proyecto tarde más tiempo en construirse.

**Es importante saber que las dependencias deben descargarse una primera ocasión y posteriormente puedes activar este modo.**

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias funcionó de maravilla!